# PDO bindValues isn't binding my values

Tags: php, pdo

I can't get bindValue to bind my values to the sql query.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO :table(:columns) VALUES(:values)";
 $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $query->bindValue(':table',$table);
 $query->bindValue(':columns',$columns);
 $query->bindValue(':values',$values);
 $query->execute();
```

When I run this, $query->execute() returns "false" and the data isn't update to the DB. I've also tried:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO :table(:columns) VALUES(:values)";
 $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $query->execute(array('table'=>$table,':columns'=>$columns,':values'=>$values));
```

and it still doesn't work.

This works but isn't what I want to do:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $table($columns) VALUES($values)";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: where do you get your $columns and $values variables?

Answer (score 2):

You are using it incorrectly, you cannot dynamically assign structural SQL values etc via the `bindParam` as it is meant for column values being inserted in / updated / tested against.

**UPDATE**

If you provide us with what the `$columns` and `$variables` (as Col. Shrapnel asked in the comments) contents generally are / where they come from, I / we maybe able to help you with a work around to your predicament.

Comment: $table = "notes";
$columns = "SchedNote";
$values = "Test insert";

Comment: What happens if you have two columns? How is that formatted, as expected with a comma? How about two values?